# How to ignore empty input when saving to database

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, database

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Data</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        /* POST it here  */
        <form  action="this.php" method="post">
            <input type='text' name='SpouseName' required/>
            <input type='text' name='SpouseAge' /> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

/* Here is the PHP CODE */
<?php   
include 'dbh2.php'; 
$SpouseName = $_POST['SpouseName']; 
$SpouseAge = $_POST['SpouseAge'];  
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (SpouseName, SpouseAge) VALUES ('$SpouseName', '$SpouseAge')";    
$result = $conn->query($sql);   
?>
```

I want to ignore empty input like spouseage how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the values have been set with **[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**, and check that they're not empty with **[`!empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)**:

```
$SpouseName = $_POST['SpouseName'];
$SpouseAge = $_POST['SpouseAge'];
if (isset($SpouseName) && !empty($SpouseName) && isset($SpouseAge) && !empty($SpouseAge)) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO test (SpouseName,SpouseAge) VALUES ('$SpouseName','$SpouseAge')";
} else {
  echo "The values weren't set or were empty!";
}
```

Though note that it's better to check the `$_POST` values are set and not empty in and of themselves before assigning to the variables:

```
if (isset($_POST['SpouseName']) && !empty($_POST['SpouseName'])) {
  $SpouseName = $_POST['SpouseName']
}
if (isset($_POST['SpouseAge']) && !empty($_POST['SpouseAge'])) {
  $SpouseAge = $_POST['SpouseAge'];
}
if ($SpouseName && $SposeAge) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO test (SpouseName,SpouseAge) VALUES ('$SpouseName','$SpouseAge')";
} else {
  echo "The values weren't set or were empty!";
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Looks like you've spelt the second variable wrong in: if ($SpouseName && $SposeAge) { -- $SpouseAge

Comment: @giollianosulit -- Good spotting! Not really sure how that happened haha. I've fixed that now :)

Comment: i have to many input i just sample 2 inputs

how can i ignore empty inputs when i save to database it says Unidentified index but the input that was filled is saved on database

Comment: You do it just as above; simply specify each of the different POSTS. An undefined index is another issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I Divided the Queries into 2 sections. Now you can do form validation for each separate input and test the data. I also placed isset for the submit to check if it has been clicked.  WE then test if it is empty if not insert and we do it for each.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$SpouseName = $_POST['SpouseName'];
$SpouseAge = $_POST['SpouseAge'];
if(!$SpouseName==''){$sql = "INSERT INTO test (SpouseName) VALUES ('$SpouseName')";}
if(!$SpouseAge ==''){$sqlb = "INSERT INTO test (SpouseAge) VALUES ('$SpouseAge')";
} 
}
```

Comment: With this code, two different queries will be executed and will insert 2 different records in db which is different from the OP needs...